# DevExpress XAF - Display Format Of Grid View Group Footers

Tags: winforms, gridview, devexpress, grouping, xaf

I am using DevExpress XAF and have enabled the Group Footer for grid views, i have then set this Group Footer to be the sum of all the records in that group which works fine. However the records are formatted as currency ({0:C}) and then in the Group Footer it calculates them correctly but just shows them as a standard numeric not formatted as currency.

How can I get the Group Footer sum to format as currency (the same as the individual rows)?

Cheers.

Comment: Additional Into - When i run the project and go into the grid view and right click on the Group Footer and click any of Min, Max or Sum (Which is already selected) then the display format in the footer is correctly formatted to a currency, it is just not getting set by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a View Controller in the Win Module Project which when activated on the View_ControlsCreated event fires the following code for each view and every column within that view which i wish to edit.

```
if (View.Id == "ViewId")
 {
      GridControl grid = (GridControl)View.Control;
      GridView view = (GridView)grid.FocusedView;
      view.Columns.View.OptionsSelection.MultiSelect = true;
      view.OptionsSelection.MultiSelectMode = GridMultiSelectMode.CellSelect;
      view.OptionsView.GroupFooterShowMode = GroupFooterShowMode.VisibleAlways;
      {
          GridColumn valueColumn = view.Columns["ColumnName"];
          GridGroupSummaryItem valueSummaryItem = new GridGroupSummaryItem();
          valueSummaryItem.FieldName = "FieldName";
          valueSummaryItem.SummaryType = SummaryItemType.Sum;
          valueSummaryItem.DisplayFormat = "DisplayFormat";
          valueSummaryItem.Tag = 1;
          valueSummaryItem.ShowInGroupColumnFooter = valueColumn;
          view.GroupSummary.Add(valueSummaryItem);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding your `GroupSummary` via code, it should look something like this

```
gridView
   .GroupSummary
   .Add(SummaryItemType.Sum, amountPropertyName, colAmount, "Sum {0:C}");
```

For DevExpress related questions, the best place to ask is their [Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/)